# the value of Determinant in congruence problem

Tags: linear-algebra

Question:If $ J= $$\begin {pmatrix} 0 & I_n \\ -I_n & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$ $,$ A $ is a $2n$-order real matrix, and $AJA^T = J$, prove $det(A) = 1$.

It's easy to know that $det(A) = ±1$. Then I assume $A = $$\begin {pmatrix} B_n & C_n \\ D_n & E_n \end{pmatrix}$$ $, and know that$$BC^T = CB^T$$$$DE^T = ED^T$$$$BE^T - CD^T = I_n$$ But I don't know what to do next. It doesn't seem to be a good method.

Comment: This is usually proved using Pfaffian, but there are other elementary proofs as well. See e.g. the [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.04240.pdf) cited by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_matrix#Determinantal_properties).